# implicit function theorem on manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose that $M\subseteq \mathbb R^D$ is $d$-dimensional compact submanifold with $0\in M$, having reach $\tau>0$. Thus, for every $p\in M$, $\exp_p:B_{T_pM}(p,\tau)\rightarrow B_M(p,\tau)$ is a diffeomorphism. Can we say there is $\phi:B_{T_0M}(0,\tau)\rightarrow \mathbb R^{D-d}$ such that $\exp_0(u)=(u,\phi(u))$?

Comment: Keeping in mind that the exponential of a vector lies at the end of a path of the same length as the vector, this is clearly not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider for example $M=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2| |(x_1,x_2)-(0,1)|=1\}$. Then $exp_0(u)=(sin(u),1-cos(u))$.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the example.